# Sublime text, right click on file and it automatically opens, but I want to delete the file. Why?

Tags: sublimetext

Sublime text, right click on file and it automatically opens, problem is I want to delete the file. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior by opening **`Preferences -> Settings-User`** and adding the following:

```js
"preview_on_click": false
```

If the file is empty, make sure you wrap the settings in curly braces `{ }`. If there are multiple settings, make sure there is a comma `,` after each line except the last one.

When you set this to `false`, you will need to double-click on files in the sidebar to open them.

Comment: excellent thank you, yet when I right click delete it does not delete? I'm on linux permissions are same user as sublime